# Tomcat Axis2 - Not seeing spring jars

Tags: spring, tomcat, configuration, apache-axis

I've been reading information online about this for several hours now and I'm at a loss.

I've successfully got Tomcat 7 running with Axis2 in a servlet. I can view non-spring based jsps just fine. The moment I try to integrate spring the whole thing breaks. My server log gives me the following error.

```
   SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1591)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 25 more
```

I've got Spring 3.1.0.M1, and the jars are in the classpath for Axis2 (%AXIS2CLASSPATH%), and for Tomcat, configured via the toolbar interface for the service. This is all up on windows 7 x64.

I'm trying to get the pojoguidespring sample that came with Axis2 working.

This is a clean install so I can tear it down if I need to. Could someone please give me some detailed directions? I'm going crazy here.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

While `javax/servlet/ServletContextListener` is not a Spring class, it's only getting called when I include Springs context configuartion info in web.xml, like so

`<context-param> 
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value> 
</context-param> 
<listener> 
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener>`

The servlet-api.jar is in the classpath (lib directory) for Axis2 and Tomcat. Checking the jar shows that `javax/servlet/ServletContextListener` is most definitely available. Can I please get another suggestion?

Comment: The problem occurs when I add the following lines to web.xml. From what I understand, these lines are supposed to get Axis2 to set up contect info for spring.
`<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>`

Answer (score 2):

`javax/servlet/ServletContextListener`  is not a Spring class; it's part of the servlet.jar that should come with Tomcat.

`%AXIS2CLASSPATH%` suggests to me that you are depending on environment variables for CLASSPATH.  This is a bad idea.  Tomcat ought to be able to manage everything just fine if you put the JARs you need in the proper places.  No need for environment variables or altering any start up scripts.

Your CLASSPATH is broken; I'd fix that.

Comment: The reason I thought it was a spring based issue is that this error only shows in the log when I try to include the spring based example. I get a clean start without a spring app.

As far as fixing the classpath goes: The documentation all points to that environment variable. The build.xml file seems to include any file in the lib directory. I've got the spring.jars in the lib directory. 

Is there some other location I should be going to to fix the classpath?

Comment: Axis2 CLASSPATH :  So, what I've learned is that while every other java based application I've used requires a classpath environment variable of some sort, Axis2, by default, is configured to use any jar in it's lib directory. The trick here is that if you are using it as a servlet, you need to rebuild your WAR any time you add new dependencies. This didn't solve the issue with spring, however.